# PowerShell Cmdlet use unapproved verb in c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm building a PowerShell module from C#. Sadly I did not find a suitable Verb-Noun pair in my case and I'm perfectly fine with that. I'm not that afraid of my cmdlet being less discoverable. For example

```cs
[Cmdlet("<I do not want a verb>", "Foo")]
public class Foo : PSCmdlet
{
  protected override void ProcessRecord()
  {
    WriteObject("Foo");
  }
}
```

I tried using empty strings, but PowerShell doesn't let me load the module by using `Import-Module`. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Well, I think using a verb and noun would be a splendid workaround. :P If you have no suitable pair, try an unsuitable pair, like `Do-Foo`. But really, there are so many [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) that it would be extremely unusual not to find *anything* suitable.

Comment: Honestly, I found some but they either alter the meaning in a way or they provide no insight like: `Use-Foo`. I'm using it since I'm actually calling `Foo`.

Comment: "I did not find a suitable Verb-Noun pair in my case and I'm perfectly fine with that. I'm not that afraid of my cmdlet being less discoverable" - sounds like you want something _other_ than a cmdlet then...

Comment: If you are calling `Foo`, then `Invoke-Foo` is appropriate for synchronous calls and `Start-Foo` is appropriate for asynchronous ones.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I wrote that especially because PowerShell warned me: `WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'Foo' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. ...`. Moreover, in the docs there is a paragraph: `This is a recommendation but not a rule; in particular, it need not be respected for command aliases mimicking well known commands from other environments.`. This is exactly my case, but I find it impossible to not respect these recommendations from `C#`. In PS you can write whatever name you like for your cmdlet.

Comment: @Vivere Can you describe your situation a bit further? If you're trying to create an alias, you'd define that _in addition_ to whatever `Verb-Noun` name you assign to the cmdlet.

Comment: For example, the `Pester` module does not use appropriate Verbs. It uses `Describe`, `It`, `Mock` etc. What `Verb` would you assign to those cmdlets? Let's say I want to rewrite `Pester` but from `C#` and really caring for the name `It`, would that be impossible? Isn't that too high of a restriction? I did not think about aliases, I don't really use them but if there is no other way I will give it a shot.

Comment: Pester's `Describe`, `It`, `Mock` etcetera are *not* cmdlets -- they're functions (as revealed by `Get-Command`). I have no idea if you can expose functions from C#.

Comment: My terminology is a bit off since I didn't really write `PowerShell` from `C#` yet, I'm just starting. I considered functions decorated with the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute, Cmdlets.

Comment: Yes, my bad -- I thought `CmdletBinding` would bestow the hallowed state of cmdlet on functions (as they certainly behave like it), but `Get-Command` disagrees. Well, then I'd just pull out the argument that testing frameworks are generally exempt from all kinds of conventions if it makes testing code easier to write. So yes, if you wanted to write Pester from C# (or the equivalent) you might have a legitimate use case. If all else fails, you can write a cmdlet with any name you like in PowerShell, that calls any .NET class you like written in C#, it just makes packaging the module trickier.